# Hide work Google Keep items on the weekend

Tags: google-keep

In Google Keep I store both personal and work-related items. Over the weekend I don't like to see any of the work-related items, so I can stay in my Zen state of mind. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

The closest I can find is to use the "Label" function to apply labels to the items you want to see all of the time, and either label the work related items as "Work" or simply leave them unlabeled.

Then you can change your view to only see those notes that have the label you want. So, for instance, to only see your personal items on the weekend, select the "Personal" label. (This is located on the main menu.) To go back to seeing all of your notes on Monday morning, simply open the main menu and select "Notes" at the top of the menu.

There are four default labels ("Check into", "Inspiration", "Personal", "Work") but you can of course create new ones or remove the ones that are there.

Unfortunately, there is not currently a way to "exclude" a label from view, only to limit the view to a label.

More about labels from [Google Support](https://support.google.com/keep/answer/6191044).

Comment: True, but problem is when opening the app, you'll still initially see all the items, including the work items. I guess I could start opening Keep from a bookmark which goes into a particular non-work label.

Comment: As I implied, it's an imperfect solution, but is probably as close as you can get with the app in its current state.